# Is there a way to have the layout change when the user flips device

Tags: android

I have code to set a different layout for portrait and landscape.  Is there a way to change the layout while the activity is running, if the user flips the device?

Code to set layout

```
void SetView()
{
   int w=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
   int h=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

   if (w>h)
      setContentView(R.layout.mainHor);
   else
      setContentView(R.layout.mainVer);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two new folders in res called layout-land and layout-port. Put your landscape layout in layout-land and your portrait in layout-port. Make sure the xml files have the **same** name.

Also, as was mentioned in the comments, making just the layout-land folder is good enough as long as you also have a default xml for the Activity in the layout folder. If for any reason Android can't find the layout needed in the alternative layout-[orientation] folder, it will take what it finds in layout.

Comment: Actually just `layout` and `layout-land` will suffice.

Comment: Yes, but new users should use more structure, helps with debugging.

Comment: I disagree. With your method, the user is now _forced_ to have two layouts for each possibility, whereas with the default `layout` folder you get a fallback for any orientation.

Comment: Remember: you can't assume that the device's default layout is portrait.  Generally, if you're going to have separate layouts for portrait and landscape, you should create separate layout-land/ and layout-port/ resource directories.  Only put things in layout/ if they will be used in both orientations.  The developer isn't "forced" to do anything.  I routinely create all three of layout/, layout-land/, and layout-port/.  Orientation-agnostic activities go in layout/ and orientation-sensitive activities go into the other two.

Comment: Thank you this is a lot more simple then what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

make two folder under `res` folder with name `layout` and `layout-land`. Put seprate layouts for portrait and landscape.

and then override `onConfigurationChanged`

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            setContentView(R.layout.homepage_screen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                setContentView(R.layout.mainHor);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                setContentView(R.layout.mainVer);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(configuration);
    if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                setContentView(R.layout.landscape_layout);
    } else if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                setContentView(R.layout.portrait_layout);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Catching configuration changes in code is discouraged.  A lot more than layout can change when the configuration changes, and doing everything right in software is very hard.  Better to have separate layout resource folders.  See also onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() for a way to make the configuration switch go much quicker.